# bootbox dialog for multi element use same class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bootbox

I am using bootbox for my framework.
I have many span elements, when click to span will open a dialog for this span.

[SPAN 1 class=span-edit-value]
[SPAN 2 class=span-edit-value]
[SPAN 3 class=span-edit-value]
[SPAN 4 class=span-edit-value]

But when i click to first span, bootbox open all dialog. When i click to second span, bootbox open 3 dialog (2,3,4)

```
$('.span-edit-value').click(function(e){
  var html_form_change_option = '<div class="form-edit-option-addition-meta">test</div>';
  bootbox.dialog({
      message: html_form_change_option,
      title: 'test'
   });
});
```

Please help me fix it

Thanks you
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code it may work for you

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootbox.min.js"></script>`//you can add you own bootbox url i just download 4.2.0 and it's working fine.

`<span class="span-edit-value">span 1</span>
<span class="span-edit-value">span 2</span>
<span class="span-edit-value">span 3</span>
<span class="span-edit-value">span 4</span>`

Below is tha jQuery code for click event

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".span-edit-value").click(function(){
         var html_form_change_option = '<div class="form-edit-option-addition-meta">test</div>';
          bootbox.dialog({
              message: html_form_change_option,
              title: 'test'
});
});
</script>
```